# Subtract the contribution of one normal distribution from another dependent normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

I have a normal distribution (*Resolution*), the FWHM of which is used to quantify the performance of an algorithm. The algorithm calculates a resolution, and the FWHM defines the resolution achievable. The data being analysed by the algorithm however has a distribution itself due to experimental effects which can be described by another normal distribution (*Divergence* - calculated through simulation) and leads to a larger FWHM of *Resolution*.

How can I calculate the FWHM *Resolution* without the contribution of *Divergence* if I know the FWHM of both distributions already (through experiment and simulation)? The difference between these I expect to be a normal distribution that is sans the contribution of *Divergence*.

In other words, how do you remove the contribution of one distribution from another when it's dependent on it. Can the contribution of one normal distribution just be subtracted in quadrature from the other?

Comment: Short answer: yes.  On the theoretical level of the *distributions,* this is a trivial consequence of the fact that the variances of sums of independent random variables add (*bilinearity*).  On the level of *data* and *estimates,* it's a bit more complicated because it's possible for the resulting *estimated* variance to be negative.